# What is => operator in this code

Tags: c#, operators

I am using ThreadPool with the follwoing code:-

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
                (o =>
                MyFunction()
                );
```

I am not sure what does `o=>` does in this code. Can anyone help me out.

Comment: I think you mean `() => MyFunction()`, this is a lambda without a parameter

Comment: @Mystere Man QueueUserWorkItem expects an instance of WaitCallback which is a delegate for methods that take and object and return void. So, while strange, the signature is correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It describes a lambda (anonymous) function. In this case it's a function that takes one argument, o, and then executes MyFunction (although in this case it's basically throwing the value of o away). It's equivalent to:

```
void Foo(object o) //We know that Foo takes an object and returns void because QueueUserWorkItem expects an instance of type WaitCallback which is a delegate that takes and object and returns void
{
  MyFunction();
}

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Foo) // or ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Foo));
```

The type of o is inferred based on whatever QueueUserWorkItem expects. QueueUserWorkItem expects type WaitCallback so in this case o should be of type object because WaitCallback is delegate for methods with one parameter of type object that return void.

As for the *meaning* of this particular code fragment; you're basically adding a function (work item) to a queue that will be executed by one of the threads in the pool (when it becomes available). That particular code fragment just describes a nice, succinct way of passing in the function without having to go through the trouble of fully defining a class method.

Incidentally, I, and others, tend to read => as 'such that'. Some people read it as 'goes to'.

Comment: Just to clarify, => is the operator and o is the parameter being passed in. Have a peek at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx for further details.

Comment: @lzcd: I wouldn't call it an operator. It's just the syntax which separates the parameters from the body of the lambda.

Comment: If i understand correctly then if i want to pass some parameters to my function then i can do it like this:-

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o=>MyFunction(o));

Answer (score 3):

This is the C# syntax for a lambda expression.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

It is in many ways an inline delegate definition.  It saves you the tediousness of defining an extra function to use as the delegate target.

```
private object Target(object state) {
  MyFunction();
}

...
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Target));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's declaring an anonymous method. Basically, you are passing a method whose body is `{ MyFunction(); }` as a parameter to the QueueUserWorkItem method. I haven't checked, but it should also be also equivalent to:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(MyFunction);
```

Comment: Not quite I don't think. QueueUserWorkItem expects a delegate that accepts one object as an argument; hence wrapping `MyFunction` in a lambda.